# VeraCrypt version 1.19 not responding on Windows 10

Tags: windows, encryption, crash

Right after installing VeraCrypt version 1.19 on Windows 10, the application keeps crashing with the "not responding" message in the home screen.

Known facts: 
- This is the latest version of the application. 
- I have not encrypted anything yet (of course, because the application keeps crashing).
- I am using Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Have you reported the problem to the VeraCrypt developers?

Comment: compile the software on your own: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets there are already commits after 1.19 was released. maybe it is already fixed

Comment: I have not reported to developers, I am trying to find a solution before reporting a possible bug. 
I have the latest version of the software.